# how i can make php that cut part of photos?

Tags: php, html, mysql, photo

I have a project I'm working on right now... I want to know is there any idea how i can make an app that every time i upload a photo it, with the specific size it cut like the middle part only and puts it on another photo i chose.
here is an example : 1 - Upload man photo with white background 2- it takes the middle part of the photo 3 - i upload a garden photo and the man shows there.
I just need to know the way to make it.
Is there also a way to delete white backgrounds like Chrom key or something?

example
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You make a Bitmap for the original file first and then use some Bitmap or BitmapFactory funcions to copy part of the bitmap to a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [ImageMagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

ImageMagick allows you to cut, crop, colorize, etc.  For example, here is some sample code showing how to crop a photo:

```
<?php
function cropImage($imagePath, $startX, $startY, $width, $height) {
    $imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($imagePath));
    $imagick->cropImage($width, $height, $startX, $startY);
    header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
    echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
}

?>
```

A brief scan of questions regarding ImageMagick and PHP will be helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagemagick+php

##### Resources:

https://phpimagick.com/

[ImageMagick options and settings](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/efficient-image-resizing-with-imagemagick/#optimal-settings-for-imagemagick)

[Using ImageMagick to crop from center with PHP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATojKZjAg84)

Comment: if I have pics with a green screen... can I use ImageMagick to let it automatically cut the green color and past the person on another picture?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that question. However, if you ask this as a separate question (make sure you add the tag ImageMagick), several ImageMagick experts will read that new question. *Please make sure to close out this question when you are ready (i.e. choose a "best answer") - that will help us out.*